# Does there exist a sequence $a_1, a_2, . . . \in \{−1, 1\}$ such that $\sum_n \frac{a_n a_{n+1} \cdots \,a_{n+k}}{n}$ converges for all $k\geq0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

> Does there exist a sequence $a_1, a_2, . . . \in \{−1, 1\}$ such that $\sum_n \frac{a_n a_{n+1} \cdots \, a_{n+k}}{n}$ converges for all $k \geq 0$?

I got this problem in my probability course and couldn't get to a solution.

I want to start by asking why would a probability approach work here? 
If I set $X_1 ,...$ i.i.d that can get $-1$ or $1$ with probability $1/2$. Even if I prove the chance to get such a sequence is zero, there still might be a very specific sequence that would will hold for the problem. Just the chance of getting such sequence is zero.

This thought made me think I need to prove such a sequence exists. I tried using Kolmogorov's three-series theorem but havn't gotten much progress.

Thank you,

Comment: Can you set $Z_{n, k} = X_{n+k}...X_n$ and show that $(Z_{n, k})_n$ are independent for each $k$ then use Kolmogorov three series theorem for each $k$, and take intersection of all the events which would then have probability $1$ so we are guaranteed that for some $a_n$ all of those series converge?

Comment: I dont think $Z_{n,k}$ are independent for example: $X_1X_2X_3 , X_2X_3X_4,X_3X_4X_5$ are not independent. I might have not understand what you ment

Comment: I'm also having trouble using Kolmogorov three series since from (1) $|Z_{n,k}|=1$ so i need to choose constant A>1 but then from (3) I get $\sum 1_{X_n<A}<\infty$ so A<1
The number represent the condition for Kolmogorov theorem from wiki
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem

Comment: I'm just throwing ideas around, not saying that it actually works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $(X_i)_{i\geqslant1}$ be an i.i.d. sequence such that $\mathbb P(X_1=1)=\mathbb P(X_1=-1)=1/2$.
For a fixed $k\geqslant 0$, let $M_N:=\sum_{n=1}^NX_n\dots X_{n+k}/n$. Then $(M_N)$ is a martingale with respect to the filtration $(\mathcal F_n)$, where $\mathcal F_n=\sigma\left(X_i,1\leqslant i\leqslant n+k\right)$.
Moreover, $\sup_{N\geqslant 1}\mathbb E\left[M_N^2\right]<\infty$
(because the increments defining $M_N$ are centered and pairwise orthogonal).
Therefore, the martingale convergence theorem guarantees that $(M_N)$ converges almost surely.

Comment: Can you explain why $sup \mathbb{E}[M_N^2]<\infty$
I feel like $\mathbb{E}[M_N^2]=\mathbb{E}[\sum_n^N 1+\sum_{1\leq{i}\leq{j}\leq{n}} Y_i Y_j] =N\rightarrow \infty$ 
Where Y_n=X_n...X_{n+k}

Comment: @OrenDiskin The sum $\sum_n^N$ should be $\sum_n^N1/n$.

Comment: Or rather $\sum_n^N1/n^2$.